# Optaplanner Construction Heuristics based on entity properties

Tags: optaplanner, heuristics

I am trying to create a CH configuration that makes the most sense for my problem. And I think I figured out a way. But for that I need to know, is there a way in CH to cycle just through all entities that have a given property?

For example, instead of cycling for a given value being assigned to all computers (case 1, n+1 = all computers), cycle first through computers with 4 CPU and assign the process to a value (case 2, p+1 = number of computers with 4 CPU). Then cycle through other computers with a different number of CPU for the same value and repeat until all values are assigned.

case 1:

```
Move-0: Computer 1- Process 1 ...

Move-1: Computer 2-Process 1 ...

Move-3: Computer 3- Process 1 ...

...

Move-n: Computer n- Process 1...
```

case 2:

```
Move-0: Computer 1- Process 1 ...

Move-1: Computer 12-Process 1 ...

Move-3: Computer 15- Process 1 ...

...

Move-p: Computer p - Process 1...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strength comparator feature to give precedence like CPU count. For more information [Planning value strength](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.1.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#planningValueStrength). On the heuristic phase, construction algorithm must be [STRONGEST_FIT](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.1.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#strongestFit).

Comment: The thing is what STRONGEST_FIT does is it assigns one entity at a time -if I am not wrong-. I want the solver to cycle through all planning entities with the same property (Computers 1,...,n that all have 4 CPU) for one value (Process 1) and then select a move within those (e.g Computer 2 - Process 1). Then to cycle through all computers that have 2 CPU (computers n,...,p) and select within all those moves the best computer for the process. And so on.